# Is checking IQueryable<T>.Any() necessary?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have methods that then chain on to others, passing IQueryable. Here's a cut down sample.

```
    public static IQueryable<Deal> Deals(this DbContext context)
    {
        Guard.ThrowIfNull(context, "context");

        var r = new ReadRepo<Deal>(context);

        return r.FindBy()
            .Include("Deals_SitePost")
            .Include("Deals_CommunityPost")
            .Include("Deals_Preorder")
            .Include("Deals_Product")
            .Include("Deals_Sale")
            .Include("Deals_VoucherCode")
            .Include("DealSubcategories");
    }

    public static IQueryable<Deal> ByStore(this IQueryable<Deal> deals, int storeId)
    {
        return deals.Where(d => d.StoreId == storeId);
    }

    public static IQueryable<Deal> WhereFeatured(this IQueryable<Deal> deals)
    {
        return deals.Where(d => d.Deals_SitePost.IsNotNull() && d.Deals_SitePost.IsFeatured);
    }
```

As you can see, there is a starter 'Deals' and a couple of extension methods that I use to extend the query.

In this scenario is is wise to check and return where !IQueryable.Any() in terms of performance before the query statement, or will it not matter?

Comment: Performance question.... best would be to check with a `Stopwatch` or like wise and post it as an answer,

Comment: There is actually no need to check for 'Any()'. You should however check the the 'IQueryable<Deal>' is not null!

Comment: The first three rules of performance optimization: measure, measure, measure.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus - I could test it but it would probably give different results in different scenarios - I was looking for a "is it better practice" answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be faster, if `Any() == true`, but the difference will probably be negligible.

On the other hand it can be significantly slower, if the query returns something because you then have two roundtrips to the database. One to query if there is anything at all, second to actually retrieve the data.

Comment: Thats what I was looking for, a real world answer.

Answer (score 6):

I cannot see a case where it would be faster. If `Any` returns **false**, the list would have contained no element anyway. So you don't save network bandwidth, and it is unlikely that the server-side execution plan is that much better.

If `Any` returns **true** you just have introduced an unnecessary round-trip and and unnecessary query execution.

It could be faster by coincidence but not in a predictable, worthwhile way.

Comment: Thanks usr - similar answer to above which was first, but voted up.